# name of the font style of the header

Tags: fonts, header-footer

I have noticed that several maths papers have this fancy font style for the header. What is the name of the font in the following image and how can I use it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The style used for this heading is "small capitals" or "small caps", and it is often not a separate font, but an alternate style used to set the lowercase letters.

Comment: The style of the sentence is "small caps" and can be achieved (in LaTeX) with `\textsc{Description of the project to be carried out}`, but I can't immediately identify the font

Comment: Compare the font used in small capitals with the serif (roman) fonts in the [Latex Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/)